# except specific module from npm update -g / fix module version globally

Tags: node.js, npm

for certain reasons i need to hold phantomjs to a specific version. However, every time i call npm update -g all modules will be updated to the latest version. Is there any way to fix a globally installed module to a certain version?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the version number to your package, seperated by @:

```
sudo npm install <package>@<version>
```